# adding json data value

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json

I am trying to create cart using js

```
  function fuBuyNow() {

        var prodqty = 1;
        var prodid = localStorage.ls_productID;
        var prodprice = $('#ppriceoffer').html();
        var cartItem = {
            productid: prodid,
            productqty: prodqty,
            productprice: prodprice
        };
        var cartItemJSON = JSON.stringify(cartItem);
        console.log(cartItemJSON);

        var cartArray = new Array();
        // If javascript shopping cart session is not empty
        if (localStorage.getItem('shopping-cart')) {
            cartArray = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('shopping-cart'));
        }
        cartArray.push(cartItemJSON);

        var cartJSON = JSON.stringify(cartArray);
        localStorage.setItem('shopping-cart', cartJSON);

    }
```

now i have cart data in an array, I want to sum of `productid` = 10005, `productid` = 10001 price and create new array

```js
var obj = "[{"slno":"1","productid":"10001","qty":"1","price":"250"},{"slno":"2","productid":"10005","qty":"1","price":"350"},{"slno":"3","productid":"10001","qty":"1","price":"250"},{"slno":"4","productid":"10003","qty":"1","price":"450"},{"slno":"5","productid":"10005","qty":"1","price":"350"}]";
```

Comment: Please share the array result that you're after and what you've tried so far that isn't working (what specifically are you stuck with and what isn't working?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this by using JavaScript's array methods along with jQuery if you're working with DOM elements. Here's how you can do it:

```js
var obj = [{"slno":"1","productid":"10001","qty":"1","price":"250"},{"slno":"2","productid":"10005","qty":"1","price":"350"},{"slno":"3","productid":"10001","qty":"1","price":"250"},{"slno":"4","productid":"10003","qty":"1","price":"450"},{"slno":"5","productid":"10005","qty":"1","price":"350"}];

// Filter the array to get only the items with productid = 10005 or productid = 10001
var filteredArray = obj.filter(function(item) {
    return item.productid === "10005" || item.productid === "10001";
});

// Calculate the total price
var totalPrice = filteredArray.reduce(function(acc, item) {
    return acc + parseInt(item.price);
}, 0);

// Create a new array with the total price
var newArray = [{ "totalPrice": totalPrice }];

console.log(newArray);
```

This code filters the original array to include only items with productid equal to "10005" or "10001", then calculates the total price of those items, and finally creates a new array with the total price. You can use this newArray to display or manipulate the total price as needed. If you have any further questions, feel free to ask!

**Update 1:**

```js
var obj = [
    {"slno":"1","productid":"10001","qty":"1","price":"250"},
    {"slno":"2","productid":"10005","qty":"1","price":"350"},
    {"slno":"3","productid":"10001","qty":"1","price":"250"},
    {"slno":"4","productid":"10003","qty":"1","price":"450"},
    {"slno":"5","productid":"10005","qty":"1","price":"350"}
];

var aggregatedArray = [];

obj.forEach(function(item) {
    var existingItem = aggregatedArray.find(function(aggregatedItem) {
        return aggregatedItem.productid === item.productid;
    });

    if (existingItem) {
        existingItem.qty = parseInt(existingItem.qty) + 1;
        existingItem.price = parseInt(existingItem.price) + parseInt(item.price);
    } else {
        aggregatedArray.push({
            slno: item.slno,
            productid: item.productid,
            qty: item.qty,
            price: item.price
        });
    }
});

var newArray = JSON.stringify(aggregatedArray);

console.log(newArray);
```

try this

Comment: but i want like this
var obj2 ="[{"slno":"1","productid":"10001","qty":"2","price":"500"},{"slno":"2","productid":"10005","qty":"2","price":"700"},{"slno":"4","productid":"10003","qty":"1","price":"450"}]";

Comment: its helpful but how to rearrange slno

Comment: You want something like this?
 [
    {"slno":1,"productid":"10001","qty":2,"price":500},
    {"slno":2,"productid":"10005","qty":2,"price":700},
    {"slno":3,"productid":"10003","qty":1,"price":450}
]